# Different keys not working on laptop (Windows 10) in different setup

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, hardware-failure, hp

I have an HP AU 620 TX. Some keys are not working on the laptop keyboard. The first few days it was happening intermittently but now every time I restart it, those particular keys are not working. On plugging in an external keyboard, those keys are working but other specific keys are not working.

Please note that the on-screen keyboard is working.

Images for reference (blank keys are not working):

Laptop keyboard:
[image: Laptop keyboard]

External keyboard:
[image: External keyboard]

Earlier when I tested the same external keyboard, keys like <kbd>O</kbd> and <kbd>L</kbd> were also not working.

Among the <kbd>Enter</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> keys only the leftmost ones are working in both setups but it appears for the other one as well on the website.

My concern is - if I buy a wireless keyboard, will it be worth it in this scenario? Should I be assured that it will work unless that keyboard itself has issues?

Comment: Please could you clarify: when you plug in the external keyboard, do all the keys on that work? (It reads as if some keys on the external keyboard don't work, but they are different ones from those that don't work on the internal keyboard.)

Comment: Try unplugging the internal keyboard, then connecting the external one. It could be a key is depressed, blocking the external board. BTW, a re[placement keyboard can be found for US$13 or so: https://www.amazon.com/s?k=HP+AU+620+TX+replacement+keyboard